# Error: 502 Bad Gateway with Google Login (custom domains)

Tags: authentication, web, gmail

This error happens when a new user register using a custom domain gmail address (xx@domain.com), it doesn't happen with a regular gmail address.

Our app has been approved by Google, then what's the fix?

Thank you!

Google have no clue.

Comment: Please include your code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.